# Using joins only if there is data in primary table

Tags: sql-server, join, case, sql-like

I have following scenario.

I have two tables.

First table

```
SELECT * FROM #REVENUECODES

    PROCCODE
    --------
    RA
    MA
```

Second table

```
SELECT * FROM #REVENUECODESXYZ

      PROCCODE
      ---------
      RA123
      MA325
      MA582
      XY123
      YW123
```

Exceptected result

I need to search in `#REVENUECODESXYZ`, which starts with (`#REVENUECODES.PROCCODE`)

Following query gives me the output.

```
SELECT 
    XY.PROCCODE 
FROM 
    #REVENUECODESXYZ  XY  
INNER JOIN 
    #REVENUECODES AB ON XY.PROCCODE LIKE (AB.PROCCODE+'%')
```

I get this:

```
    PROCCODE
    --------
    RA123
    MA325
    MA582
```

And this is the desired output as well.

**Failing scenario:**

If there are no values in table `#REVENUECODES`, then I should get all data in `#REVENUECODESXYZ` which is not happening now. With my current code, if no data is there in  `#REVENUECODES`, then because of join condtition I am getting an empty result.

I am trying to do somehting like this.

```
SELECT 
    XY.PROCCODE 
FROM 
    #REVENUECODESXYZ  XY  
INNER JOIN
    #REVENUECODES AB ON ( (XY.PROCCODE LIKE (AB.PROCCODE+'%'))
                          or
                          (isnull(AB.PROCCODE, '') = '')
                         )
```

But this query gives me nothing when `#REVENUECODES` is empty, when it should give me everything in  `#REVENUECODESXYZ`.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: then it will fail in first scenario. I need a code which works in both the scenario.

Comment: you said: "then I should get all data in #REVENUECODESXYZ". That's achieved with a LEFT JOIN. You may forget something in the question.

Comment: Apologies, what I meant is that single query should work in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I initially didn't read your question correctly.

The result set seems to have two distinct selection 'branches' - the cleanest way I can think of is to union the two results together, and ensure mutual exclusivity with the `NOT EXISTS` (the `INNER JOIN` will return nothing if the RHS table has no rows)

```
 SELECT XY.PROCCODE 
 FROM #REVENUECODESXYZ XY
    INNER JOIN #REVENUECODES AB on
     XY.PROCCODE like (AB.PROCCODE+'%')

UNION

 SELECT XY.PROCCODE
 FROM #REVENUECODESXYZ XY
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #REVENUECODES)
```

Comment: No, in this case when I have data in ('#REVENUECODES'), then also I get all the data from (' #REVENUECODESXYZ' ), instead of getting filtered data.

Comment: @Rajesh My apologies, I didn't read your question correctly. I've updated. The union is a single result set.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an INNER JOIN which shows only data that matches between two tables.
If you want to see data in the `#REVENUECODESXYZ` table use a LEFT JOIN and a RIGHT JOIN for vice-versa.

Use a FULL OUTER join for all the data data ie: inner + left + right joins.

Comment: I tried that join, but that fails in first scenario where I have data in first table (REVENUECODES'). In this case also I get all the data from #REVENUECODESXYZ instead of getting filtered data.

Comment: you can't get filtered(only matched) data in left outer(it shows data in REVENUECODES and matched data)
You have to change join according to your situation